# Вывести стандартный балун яндекс карт по клику

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Существует ли простой способ, например в конфигурации карт, добавить по клику на любое место карты стандартный балун, который появляется по клику на Яндекс.Картах с описанием места?

[image: стандартный балун]

Или для этого нужно обязательно писать свой кастомный балун?

Answer (score 0):

В  JS API Яндекс.Карт есть стандартный балун, но вот, какой именно контент в нём выводить, придётся определить самому. Из коробки балун как на самих Яндекс.Картах получить не удастся.

**Как сделать балун с адресом по клику на карте**

У карты есть событие `click`, которое вам нужно слушать, и метод карты `balloon.open()`, который позволяет открыть на ней стандартный балун. [Вот тут есть интерактивный пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_properties?from=SO)

Чтобы вывести адрес в точке клика нужно добавить обратное геокодирование:

```
myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
    if (!myMap.balloon.isOpen()) {
        var coords = e.get('coords');
        ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
          var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
           myMap.balloon.open(coords, {
            contentHeader: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine(),
            contentBody: '<p>Координаты щелчка: ' + [
                coords[0].toPrecision(6),
                coords[1].toPrecision(6)
                ].join(', ') + '</p>'
         })
        });
    }
    else {
        myMap.balloon.close();
    }
});
```

**Как добавить свои кнопки в балун**

Чтобы в балуне появились кнопки, например, "маршрут" и "искать рядом", нужно создать свой макет балуна. В песочнице Яндекса есть [подробный пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout?from=SO).

В целом, кастомный макет позволяет полностью видоизменить стандартный балун - настроить его под свой дизайн или повторить дизайн Яндекс.Карт.

Кроме того, потребуется провязать кнопки с контролами на карте. То есть отдельно добавить интерфейс построения маршрутов и строку поиска.